# Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8.0_40" when open terminal on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, java-8

- I have installed jdk1.8.0_121 already and JAVA_HOME seems correct. 
  But when I open terminal, it always reminds me "Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8.0_40"". 
  [image]
- jdk1.8.0_40 was installed Previously but I hava already uninstalled this version.

Does anyone know how to remove this annoying reminder?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you show the command you typed that generated that message?

Comment: @Joe Well, i did not typed any command. When I open terminal, this message appears.

Comment: You have some Java-related thing in your .bashrc or .bash_profile or .profile that you need to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sideshowbarker, you're right. I checked all shell initialization files and found the java version was set as 1.8.0_40 in `/etc/profile`.
Thanks again.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what you id exactly?

Answer (score 12):

MacOS X does not come with Java Development Kits (JDKs) pre-installed.
Run `java -version` in the terminal and you may be prompted to install Java. *Unless you already have  JVM installed, in which case you will see the build version number.*

Next, you will be prompted to visit the Java SE Development Kit Downloads page. Download one of the JDK (Java Development Kits) with a file extension ending in `<filename>.tar.gz`.

Then run `tar -xf <filename>.tar.gz`.

Rename the newly created directory to `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 11):

i solved this using this command in terminal

```
brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
```

Answer (score 1):

please use like `brew cask install adoptopenjdk8` to install deprecated java version, esp. for Android Studio.

use `java_home -V` to show all install version of java, like:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (5):
    12.0.2, x86_64: "Java SE 12.0.2"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    12.0.1, x86_64: "OpenJDK 12.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_222, x86_64:  "AdoptOpenJDK 8"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-468, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-468, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and within `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile` for setting default jdk, like use command `setjdk 1.8`

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

function setjdk() {
    export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $@`
}
```

and with recent java/jdk v12, the Android Studio CLI not work:

```
$setjdk 12
$avdmanager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834845/unable-to-install-java8-with-homebrew

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the JVM issue while installing flutter, so my finding is particularly based on macOS 10.15.5, if you install the latest java the JVM error will still show up. For that, you have to install legacy version of java from apple.

Download the java from here
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_GB

then
Launchpad -> Other -> Script Editor

create a new document and paste the below code as it is

set theDMG to choose file with prompt "Please select javaforosx.dmg:" of type {"dmg"}
do shell script "hdiutil mount " & quoted form of POSIX path of theDMG
do shell script "pkgutil --expand /Volumes/Java\ for\ macOS\ 2017-001/JavaForOSX.pkg ~/tmp"
do shell script "hdiutil unmount /Volumes/Java\ for\ macOS\ 2017-001/"
do shell script "sed -i '' 's/return false/return true/g' ~/tmp/Distribution"
do shell script "pkgutil --flatten ~/tmp ~/Desktop/ModifiedJava6Install.pkg"
do shell script "rm -rf ~/tmp"
display dialog "Modified ModifiedJava6Install.pkg saved on desktop" buttons {"Ok"}

then  Script -> Compile and then Script -> Run.

a popup will ask you to locate your downloaded file javaforosx.pkg

Running the script will create a ModifiedJava6Install.pkg on your desktop.

Run this ModifiedJava6Install.pkg to install the legacy Java version.