# Unable to install java8 with homebrew

Tags: java, macos, java-8, homebrew

Installing `java8` with Homebrew seems to no longer be working. After running:

```
brew install caskroom/cask/java8
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Cask 'java8' is unavailable: '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/Casks/java8.rb' does not exist.
```

Simply doing:

```
brew cask install java8
```

Errors out with:

```
Error: Cask 'java8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.
```

This seems like a recent development because I remember installing it this way a few months ago. Any suggestions on how to properly install `java8` on MacOS nowadays?

Comment: this works: $ brew cask install adoptopenjdk

Answer (score 152, accepted):

New command is now :

`brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8`

Comment: Doesn't work for me but this works as suggested by Corey - `brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8`

Comment: Updated command for me is `brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8`

Comment: That worked for me too uMdRupert - thank you!

Comment: Me too, @uMdRupert. Sorry to add "me too!" but there's a lot of other stuff here to try. I had nearly given up before trying that one.

Answer (score 33):

The command is now `brew install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8 --cask`

Answer (score 31):

This has already been answered as a github issue: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/issues/7253

TLDR: the `java8` artefact refers to the Oracle distribution, which has ceased being supported/available. If you really need java 1.8 instead of the latest versions you can take a look at [`AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: Presumably the oracle distribution could have proprietary additions, while the AdoptOpenJDK distribution is just a build of the open-source OpenJDK project.

Answer (score 20):

AdoptOpenJDK has been deprecated, and transitioned to Eclipse Temurin from Adoptium. See this blog post:
https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2021/03/transition-to-eclipse-an-update/

To install Temurin Java 8, aka 1.8, with Homebrew, you can use:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask temurin8
```

If you already had AdoptOpenJDK installed using the commands in the other answers, you should uninstall it first, with:

`brew uninstall --cask adoptopenjdk8`

You can also download a .pkg for manual installation (the former link at AdoptOpenJDK now leads here):
https://adoptium.net/?variant=openjdk8

Answer (score 13):

```
brew install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8 --cask
```

In the latest changes of homebrew cask will have to be at the last.

Answer (score 3):

The command is

```
 brew cask install adoptopenjdk8-openj9
```

Fixed my problem and I can run my project in java8

java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_222

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-b10)

Eclipse OpenJ9 VM (build openj9-0.15.1, JRE 1.8.0 Mac OS X amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20190717_298 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)

OpenJ9   - 0f66c6431

OMR      - ec782f26

JCL      - f147086df1 based on jdk8u222-b10)

Answer (score 3):

Although cask remove the support for JAVA8, we can still install JAVA8 using brew.

It requires the manual download of JAVA8.dmg and add the java8.rb which could be used by cask.

**Machine**: MAC

**OS**: Mojave (10.14.6)

**JAVA version**: java 8u231

**Step-1**

Download dmg file from [Oracle Site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). You require oracle account to download the same

**Step-2**

Start the HTTP server from the folder where you downloaded the dmg file. For me it's `~/Downlaods` and I use python to start HTTP server:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

**Step-3**

Create file `java8.rb` in `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks` (where java.rb exist) and add the following:

```
cask 'java8' do
  version '8u231,b15:9eef341qase34d44fbaa21'
  sha256 'f808d11b34fa9ee7b6326b5b6dd18544496e02c84b839d94e062bd4493df5d45'

  url "http://localhost:8000/jdk-#{version.before_comma}-macosx-x64.dmg",
      cookies: {
                 'oraclelicense' => 'accept-securebackup-cookie',
               }
  name 'Oracle Java 8 Standard Edition Development Kit'
  homepage 'https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html'

  depends_on macos: '>= :yosemite'

  pkg 'JDK 8 Update 231.pkg'

  uninstall pkgutil: "com.oracle.jdk#{version.before_comma}",
            delete:  [
                       '/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin',
                       '/Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane',
                     ]

  zap trash: [
               '~/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java',
               '~/Library/Application Support/com.oracle.java.JavaAppletPlugin.plist',
               '~/Library/Application Support/com.oracle.javadeployment.plist',
             ]

  caveats do
    license 'https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/javase-license.html'
  end
end
```

**Step-4**

Now, install using brew:

`brew cask install java8`

**Note**: I got the SHA-256 checksum from the above mentioned java download link. You will have to change the version number, sha256 and
pkg sections to use the specific version you downloaded if it is not 8u231 like mine.

Comment: curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 File not found
Error: Download failed on Cask 'java8' with message: Download failed: http://localhost:8000/jdk-8u231-macosx-x64.dmg

Answer (score 3):

For Homebrew 2.7.0. the brew cask commands are disabled

The command is now changed to

**brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8**

Answer (score 3):

for new version use
`brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`

Answer (score 2):

For some of the newer version of operating system, We can use following command:

```
brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8 --cask
```

==> Caveats
Temurin is the official successor to this software:

```
brew install --cask temurin8
```

adoptopenjdk8 has been officially discontinued upstream.
It may stop working correctly (or at all) in recent versions of macOS.

Using sdkma, it is little bit easier

1. Open a new terminal and enter
   `curl -s “https://get.sdkman.io" | bash`
2. copy & paste the following in the terminal and enter
   `source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"`

   It will install the SDKMAN in your machine.
3. Check the version of the SDKMAN
   `sdk version`
4. See the available Java versions offered by SDKMAN
   `sdk list java`

   It will show all the available JDK from different vendors with supported versions.
5. Install parallel JDKs

install version 15: `sdk install java 15.0.0-librca`
install version 8: `sdk install java 8.0.265-librca`

6. Choose which one you want to use
   `sdk use java 8.0.265-librca`

Answer (score 0):

I have only managed to uninstall it with homebrew like this:

`brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies java`

Answer (score -5):

Ask the user to install Oracle JDK 8 instead of java8